# jquery fadeout issue on blur

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

I have a problem with JQuery and the following markup.

```
                <div id="ParentContainer">
                    <div class="main">
                        <div class="sub1"></div>
                        <div class="sub2">
                            text
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need the ParentContainer to fade into view when the cursor hovers over a link (outside of this markup).  this works but I need to then use the fadeout method when the cursor moves outside of the ParentContainer div.  Is that possible?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> Is that possible?

Yes it is!

```
$('#ParentContainer').bind('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Reference: [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html, Although its better to use mouseleave over mouseout, some major browsers haven't implemented them yet, and i agree that mouseleave is a better way but until all major browsers take it on i would use mouseout.

Comment: @RobertPitt: I'm not 100% sure, but I think jQuery does the cross-browser work for you in that case.

Comment: Possibly but as binding events is the part of the JavaScript engine I would of thought that it would attach the event regardless of the browser type... Not 100% sure myself.

Comment: @RobertPitt - jquery does indeed normalize this, it's an IE behavior that was desirable over `mouseout`, jQuery makes it available on all browsers, `.mouseleave()` and `.hover()` also bind to this event.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#ParentContainer').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```